# Connecting 2 controllers and have access to the first controllers propertie in the second controller

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-async

i have a problem with angular dart. 1 html file to trigger scopes and 2 controller classes
index.html

...
    
      
        {{subCtrl.user.name}} 
      
    
    ...

first controller

```dart
@Controller(
  selector: '[mainController]',
  publishAs: 'mainCtrl'
)
class MainController{
  User user = new User('testuser');
  MainController();
}
```

second controller

```dart
@Controller(
  selector: '[subController]',
  publishAs: 'subCtrl'
)
class SubController{

  @NgOneWay('user')
  User user;

  // constructor
  SubController(){
    getData();
  }

  void getData(){
    if(user != null){
      // following code is not exececutet, because user is null
      httpRequst(...);
    }
  }
}
```

when is the time user is set over @NgOneWay? seems like not before the constructor is finished. where do i have to call my method?

now i have the problem i have to make a asynch request in the getData function in the SubController class. this http request needs i.e the user.name propertie to build the domain, but user is not active when i start it in the constructor. i cant set the authentification to the second controller. there must be another option to get this working.

i tried several things with dart's future, but did not get i working for a propertie.

Answer (score 4):

This used to be the `AttachAware` interface.

```dart
class SubController implements AttachAware {
  attach() {
    getData();
    // or new Future(() => getData()); // if the line above still doesn't work - to give Angular one additional cycle to finish
  }
}
```